# Multiselect picklist in VF page missing chosen side

Tags: visualforce-component, multi-select

For some reason, my multiselect box has no 'Chosen' side:

[image: select list]

Here's my VF selectlist component:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selContact}" label="Contact Name" size="3" multiselect="true"
                rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.objType='account' && $CurrentPage.parameters.isPerson != '1'}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!contacts}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
```

I'm populating it from a class extension:

```
public List<SelectOption> getContacts()
{
    ..... other code

    for (Contact cnt : allContacts) 
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(cnt.Id, cnt.Name));
    }

    return options; 
}
```

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<apex:selectList />` tag doesn't render two lists like some of the native pages in the Salesforce UI do when making selections from a list of choices.

To make multiple selections you use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key and click on multiple items from the list.

---

You can use something like this from our very own [@metadaddy](/users/67/metadaddy) to allow you to create this side-by-side picklist in a VF page.

https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist

Comment: Ahh. Well that would explain it. Feelin pretty silly. Thanks for the explanation @Mark.

Answer (score -2):

Might be a bit late, but you can use a chosen library to represent multiselect  element way more convenient.
Pls refer to:

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: This answer isn't of much use if you don't provide an example of using it in Visualforce. While using a solution like this may sort things out on the UI side, I suspect that actually getting this to work (so that it can take data from a controller or extension, and pushing info about the selected options back into the controller/extension) is going to be somewhat miserable.